# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried the following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spvec
AS
SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS 'RNumber'
    ,vf.*
FROM LOGIN ld
    ,vehicle vf
WHERE (ld.fid = vf.fid)
    AND ld.id <> 'NA'
    AND vf.CustID <> 'None'
    AND vf.Simo <> 'None'
ORDER BY Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
```

there is none and NA text in row. e.g. there is not empty but there is values with none ,NA
here WHERE (ld.fid = vf.fid)

**UPDATE**

ld.fid is string 
and vf.fid is in int

so i try to convert

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spvec
AS
SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS 'RNumber'
    ,vf.*
FROM LOGIN ld
    ,vehicle vf
WHERE  CAST((ld.FFID=vf.FFID) AS INT)
    AND ld.id <> 'NA'
    AND vf.CustID <> 'None'
    AND vf.Simo <> 'None'
ORDER BY Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))\
```

**this show following error on update**

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Incorrect syntax near ')'.

**it throws the following error without update**

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int.

Comment: What did you expect? `'none'` is not a valid integer value.

Comment: there is none and NA text in row. e.g. there is not empty but there is values with none ,NA

Comment: Looks like `ld.id`, `vf.CustID` are integer values, why you are checking with `None` string values?

Comment: And btw: You are using *old-fashioned* JOIN... Instead of `FROM tbl1,tbl2 WHERE tbl1.ID=tbl2.FKID` better use `FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tb1.ID=tbl2.FKID`

Comment: @jarlh CHECK UPDATE

Comment: Seems like a table design issue. Why different data types for the fid columns?

Comment: @Shnugo check update

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008 version.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables actually consist of None and NA, then try this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spvec
AS
SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS 'RNumber'
    ,vf.*
FROM LOGIN ld
    ,vehicle vf
WHERE (ld.fid = cast(vf.fid as varchar(max)))
    AND cast(ld.id as varchar(2)) <> 'NA'
    AND cast(vf.CustID as varchar(4)) <> 'None'
    AND cast(vf.Simo as varchar(4)) <> 'None'
ORDER BY Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
```

Comment: Hi, the most important information comes very late :-) The OP just edited *ld.fid is string and vf.fid is in int*. So the conversion seems to occur with the first part in `WHERE`. And btw: Please do not inform everybody about your updates.

Comment: this show error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int.

Comment: @user6628729 please **state sample data** to avoid unnecessary work for you and for others... Nobody can know - without your actual table definitions and sample data, which values might fly by...

Comment: @user6628729 try updated query. i guess there was conversion issue at equals to

Comment: try adding distinct in query then

Comment: I really cant help u now until i know the table structure and get few rows of table

Comment: ok i again try and when i check with disticnt and then on order by i do this .. ORDER BY vf.*,
Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
 but this show error Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122184/discussion-between-ranjana-ghimire-and-user6628729).

Answer (score 0):

Which values do you expect in `ld.id`, `vf.CustID` and `vf.Simo`? SQL Server has no concept of the meaning of `NA` or `None`. It will just compare two values...

If `None` means `NULL` (no value exists) you might use

```
WHERE vf.CustID IS NOT NULL
```

If you have a value indicating your `None` (e.g. negative numbers) you might use something like

```
WHERE vf.CustID>=0
```

In any case you have to be aware of datatypes, whenever you want to compare values (sorting, joining, filters, constraints...)

### UPDATE

According to this

> ld.fid is string and vf.fid is in int

the problem (or better: One of your problems) is here:

```
WHERE (ld.fid = vf.fid)
```

Again: What values do you expect? A JOIN (*old-fashioned* or *real*) connects rows with identical values. Since your `vf.fid` is `INT` there will be plain numbers, nothing else.

Whatever value is in `ld.fid` it will only be identical, if it is a plain number.

You did not mention your version of SQL Server. Starting with 2012 there are very handsome `TRY_` functions. You've got some answers already...

With an earlier version you might try it with:

```
WHERE (ISNUMERIC(ld.fid) AND CAST(ld.fid AS INT) = vf.fid)
```

Another approach was a cast to VARCHAR like

```
WHERE (ld.fid=CAST(vf.fid AS VARCHAR(100)))
```

but you must be aware, that simple format differences like `100.0` or `100` (see the blanks!) would break this approach. If possible, try to keep it typesafe...

And don't forget: The error message you posted points to `None` and not to the joining fields. So I'm quite sure, that you have more than one type conversion issue...

Comment: there is none and NA text in row. e.g. there is not empty but there is values with none ,NA

Comment: Please show sample data... And explain, where this data comes from... Might be, that the `None` and `NA` is just a formatted output of another tool (similiar to `#Error`) in Excel cells...

Answer (score 0):

First you have to format your script.

The error occured dur to assigning a string value to an integer field in your table. most probably "ld.Id"

FOR SQL version from 2012.....

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE spvec
 AS
 BEGIN

   SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'RNumber',
            vf.* 
    FROM login ld,
           JOIN vehicle vf  
               ON  TRY_CONVERT(INT, ld.fid) =vf.fid 
     WHERE  ISNULL(ld.id,'') <> 'NA'
           and ISNULL(vf.CustID,'') <> 'None' 
            and vf.Simo <> 'None'  
    Order by Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))

END
```

For Older versions.....

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE spvec
 AS
 BEGIN

   SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'RNumber',
            vf.* 
    FROM login ld,
           JOIN vehicle vf  
               ON  CONVERT(INT, ld.fid) =CONVERT(INT,vf.fid )
     WHERE  ISNULL(ld.id,'') <> 'NA'
           and ISNULL(vf.CustID,'') <> 'None' 
            and vf.Simo <> 'None'  
            and ISNUMERIC(ld.fid)=1 AND ISNUMERIC(vf.fid)=1
    Order by Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))

END
```

Comment: Remove the comma from the `FROM` clause `FROM login ld,`

Comment: this show error .. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CR21' to data type int.

Comment: this show error
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Incorrect syntax near ')

Comment: @user6628729, pleaes **state the version of SQL Server** immediately. You would avoid a lot of unnecessary work for you and for others...

Comment: this show same error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int.