# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value \'08/01/1979\' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Am trying to fetch data from a SQL database on the basis of date using where clause. My SQL query is

```
select DISTINCT Name from [DataBase]  Where DOB ="+date
```

I want to change the date variable dynamically but am running into this error.
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value \'08/01/1979\' to data type int.

I'm using this query in my node.js project.

I tried using Date object but my database date is in varchar so its not working either. I tried the solutions available in stackoverflow but none worked for me.
[Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221561/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-none-to-data-type-int)

Comment: Start at the source of the problem: your date column should never have been varchar in the first place. Once you've fixed that problem, pass in a properly typed date parameter, instead of a string that needs to be escaped with \ ... also are you using SQL Server or MySQL? They're not the same. Please only tag with one or the other.

Comment: Is this question for `mysql`or for `sql server` ?